# How do I disable desktop new mail alerts?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have two Exchange mailboxes configured in Outlook.  One for my email address and another shared one.

UPDATE:

How do I disable desktop new mail alerts for the second mailbox account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xxl3ww's answer disables alerts globally. In order to disable email alerts for selected accounts you will need to perform some additional actions. First, disable alerts in Outlook options. Next, create an Outlook rule for each account you want to get alerts from that will run against all received messages (do not specify any conditions) and select **Display a Desktop Alert** as an action.

Answer (score 3):

[image]File-> Options-> Mail

There is an option under "Message Arrival" for "Display Desktop Alert". Uncheck this box.

Comment: Apologies I described my issue incorrectly.  Updated now

Comment: Do alerts still appear for only the second mailbox after following this answer?

Comment: @Geditdk you know exactly what I am trying to do here but you are just trying to be facetious

Comment: No, I was asking if the alerts are still showing for the second mailbox even though its been disabled for the primary mailbox, nothing facetious, that setting may only apply to the primary account, that's why I asked.

Comment: @Geditdk my apologies.  I am dealing with severe office politics I needed to vent haha.  When following the step it disables the primary new mail notifications which is not what I want so I have implemented the answer which I marked as correct.

Comment: @TheLearner Haha, no worries. I can definitely relate!